# Python Bottle Tutorial: cannot get anything from the HelloWorld example

Tags: python, bottle

I just installed Bottle and add it into this directory: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3`

And when I was trying to run the HelloWorld example in http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#installation
and opened `localhost:8080/hello`
, there was nothing on the page.

```
>>> from bottle import route, run
>>>
>>> @route('/hello')
... def hello():
...     return "Hello World!"
...
>>> run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
Bottle v0.13-dev server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

I don't know why, please help!

Comment: I can't reproduce this with version 0.12.7. Try to rollback to that version and see if you're still having a problem.

Comment: The example seems to be working fine, as `run` managed to bind on the port. Does it print any other Debug message after you open the page? Try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, just in case name resolution is screwing it somehow.

Comment: Yeah...Thank you all, change to 127.0.0.1 helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Replaced 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1' and got a 404 Not Found page.
However, the second example in the quickstart tutorial worked:

```
from bottle import Bottle, run

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: Thank you! although the second example still cannot work when host="localhost"

Comment: If you run route once in your original script i.e route() after the import and before everything else, it now works (using Eclipse). Then for some reason you can then remove it and the script still works.

Answer (score 0):

If its not working with localhost but it is working with 127.0.0.1, it means your network configuration is not really set up correctly.

If you are on linux or mac, check the /etc/hosts file and look for:

127.0.0.1       localhost

Windows has the same file at %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.

If the row is not there, add it.