# Bottle framework python - site cannot be reached

Tags: python, localhost, bottle

I am new to Python programming and the Bottle framework as well. I wrote up a basic hello, world program which looks like this:

```
from bottle import run, route

@route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>Hello, World</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

The output of this code is

```
Bottle v0.12.13 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

But when I enter http://localhost:8080/ in a browser, i get the error- "The site cannot be reached"

Am I missing some configuration. I am learning using [this youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_9nsFJS_pk&list=PLQgaiFtVuv4aJ0A24HEGosxw0NeTCH7P2) video

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079529/python-bottle-tutorial-cannot-get-anything-from-the-helloworld-example) ? Possible Duplicate

Comment: Same fate. No luck.

Comment: Is the browser and application on the same system ?

Comment: Yes. Both are on the same system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that no other programs are accessing the server. Are you using IPyhton as well? Just a sanity check nothing fancy.

Comment: Perfect. The IPython console was open in another window. Didn't close it at all. Thank you!